# Php + Mysql não executa exclusão nem alteração em tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Boa Tarde,

Estou tentando fazer com que uma página execute a exclusão de registros específicos em uma determinada tabela de um banco Mysql. 
Em outra tabela, esta exclusão e também a alteração funcionam perfeitamente, mas nessa não não nem apresentados os valores da tabela quando solicitados, as ambas estão praticamente iguais, reservando as devidas alterações para direcionamento em outra tabela.

Esta é a página que funciona

```html
<?php
session_start();
 if ($_SESSION['larj'] == '7be4c2') {

 include 'admin/conecta.php'; 
  
 include 'topo.php'; 
 
 $id = addslashes($_GET['id']);
 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM convidados WHERE con_id = '".$id."'";
 $consulta = mysql_query($sql,$db) or die(mysql_error());
 $qtd = mysql_num_rows($consulta);
 while($item_temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
  $convidado_array[] = $item_temp;
 } 
 /*
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($convidado_array);
 echo '</pre>';
 die();
 */ 
 
 $sql_origem = "SELECT * FROM informacoes WHERE info_tipo = 'or' AND info_atv = '1' ORDER BY info_txt";
 $consulta_origem = mysql_query($sql_origem,$db) or die(mysql_error());
 $qtd_origem = mysql_num_rows($consulta_origem);
 while($item_temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta_origem)){
  $origem_array[] = $item_temp;
 } 
 /*
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($origem_array);
 echo '</pre>';
 die();
 */ 

 $sql_vinculo = "SELECT * FROM informacoes WHERE info_tipo = 'vi' AND info_atv = '1' ORDER BY info_txt";
 $consulta_vinculo = mysql_query($sql_vinculo,$db) or die(mysql_error());
 $qtd_vinculo = mysql_num_rows($consulta_vinculo);
 while($item_temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta_vinculo)){
  $vinculo_array[] = $item_temp;
 } 
 /*
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($vinculo_array);
 echo '</pre>';
 die();
 */ 

 $sql_tratamento = "SELECT * FROM informacoes WHERE info_tipo = 'tr' AND info_atv = '1' ORDER BY info_txt";
 $consulta_tratamento = mysql_query($sql_tratamento,$db) or die(mysql_error());
 $qtd_tratamento = mysql_num_rows($consulta_tratamento);
 while($item_temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta_tratamento)){
  $tratamento_array[] = $item_temp;
 } 
 /*
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($tratamento_array);
 echo '</pre>';
 die();
 */  
 
 $sql_eventos = "SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE eve_cli_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' ORDER BY eve_nome";
 $consulta_eventos = mysql_query($sql_eventos,$db) or die(mysql_error());
 $qtd_eventos = mysql_num_rows($consulta_eventos);
 while($item_temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta_eventos)){
  $eventos_array[] = $item_temp;
 } 
 /*
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($eventos_array);
 echo '</pre>';
 die();
 */  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> Organização de Eventos - Cerimonialismo - Consultoria</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
body,td,th {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
}
a:link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
}
a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
}
a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #FF6;
}
a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
}

.pics {  
    height:  232px;  
    width:   232px;  
    padding: 0;  
    margin:  0;  
} 
 
.pics img {  
    padding: 15px;  
    border:  1px solid #ccc;  
    background-color: #eee;  
    width:  200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    top:  0; 
    left: 0 
} 

</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 
 <script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="clearbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<table width="960" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10">
 <tr>
     <td valign="bottom" align="left">
        <font face="Verdana" size="4" color="#B0855D">
            <strong>Seja bem-vindo(a), <?php echo $_SESSION['nome']; ?></strong>
        </font>
        </td>
     <td align="right" valign="middle">
         <!--
            <a href="logout.php">
            <font color="#666666">
         <img src="imagens/sair.png" border="0" width="15" align="absmiddle" />&nbsp; [ Sair ]
            </font>
            </a>
            -->
            
        </td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <td colspan="4" align="center" valign="top">
         
            <table align="center" width="100%" bgcolor="#EFEFEF" style="border:1px solid #CCC" cellpadding="5">
             <tr>
                 <td colspan="6">
                     <font color="#666666" size="2">
                      <strong>Minha &aacute;rea de cliente:</strong>
                        </font>
                        <br /><br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
                
                 <td width="16%" align="center" valign="middle">
                     <a href="convidados.php">
                     <img src="imagens/convidados_icon.png" border="0" /><br />
                        <font color="#666666" size="2">
                         <strong>Convidados</strong>
                        </font>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td width="17%" align="center" valign="middle">
                     <a href="confirmacoes.php">
                     <img src="imagens/confirmacao_icon.png" border="0" /><br />
                        <font color="#666666" size="2">
                         <strong>Confirmações</strong>
                        </font>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="17%" align="center" valign="middle">
                     <a href="relatorios.php">
                     <img src="admin/imagens/relatorio_icon.png" border="0" /><br />
                        <font color="#666666" size="2">
                         <strong>Relatórios</strong>
                        </font>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="17%" align="center" valign="middle">
                     <a href="logout.php">
                     <img src="imagens/close_icon.png" border="0" /><br />
                        <font color="#666666" size="2">
                         <strong>Sair</strong>
                        </font>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            
            <br /><br /><br />                    
            <font color="#666666" size="3">
                <strong>Deseja Excluir os Dados do Convidado: <?php echo $convidado_array[0]['con_nome']; ?>?</strong></font>
            
            <form action="confirma_del_convidado.php" method="post" name="confirma_del_convidado">
            <table width="750" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">
                        <img src="admin/imagens/voltar_icon.png" border="0" style="padding:5px;" align="absmiddle" /><font color="#555555">Voltar</font>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="40%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="60%"><font color="555555">*Campos obrigat&oacute;rios</font></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><font color="555555"><b>Evento:</b></font></td>
                <td>
                        <?php
       for($cont_ev = 0; $cont_ev < $qtd_eventos; $cont_ev++ ){
        if($eventos_array[$cont_ev]['eve_id'] == $convidado_array[0]['con_eve_id']){
         echo $eventos_array[$cont_ev][eve_nome];
        }
       }
      ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><font color="555555"><b>Nome:</b></font></td>
                <td><?php echo $convidado_array[0]['con_nome']; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><font color="555555"><b>Origem:</b></font></td>
                <td>
                        <?php
       for($cont_or = 0; $cont_or < $qtd_origem; $cont_or++ ){
        if($origem_array[$cont_or]['info_id'] == $convidado_array[0]['con_origem_id']){
         echo $origem_array[$cont_or]['info_txt'];
        }
       }
      ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><font color="555555"><b>Vínculo:</b></font></td>
                <td>
                        <?php
       for($cont_vi = 0; $cont_vi < $qtd_vinculo; $cont_vi++ ){
        if($vinculo_array[$cont_vi]['info_id'] == $convidado_array[0]['con_vinculo_id']){
         echo $vinculo_array[$cont_vi]['info_txt'];
        }
       }
      ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right" valign="top"><font color="555555"><b>Tratamento:</b></font></td>
                <td>
                     <?php
       if($convidado_array[0]['con_tratamento_id'] == '0'){
        echo $convidado_array[0]['con_tratamento_p'];
       } else {
        for($cont_tr = 0; $cont_tr < $qtd_tratamento; $cont_tr++ ){
         if($tratamento_array[$cont_tr]['info_id'] == $convidado_array[0]['con_tratamento_id']){
          echo $tratamento_array[$cont_tr]['info_txt'];
         }
        }
       }
      ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><font color="555555"><b>Quantidade de Adultos:</b></font></td>
                <td><?php echo $convidado_array[0]['con_qtd_adultos']; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><font color="555555"><b>Quantidade de Crianças:</b></font></td>
                <td><?php echo $convidado_array[0]['con_qtd_criancas']; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                 <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="<?php echo $convidado_array[0]['con_id']; ?>" />
                 <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Excluir" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
            
  </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<table width="960" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="center">
         
        </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
 include 'rodape.php';

 } else {
  echo "<script> window.location = 'area_cli_login.php'; </script>";
  die();    
 }
?>
```

essa é a página que executa a exclusão que funciona:

```html
<?php
session_start();
 if ($_SESSION['larj'] == '7be4c2') {

  include 'admin/conecta.php'; 
   
   $id = addslashes($_POST['id']);
   //$atv    = addslashes($_POST['atv']);
   
   $sql = "DELETE FROM convidados WHERE con_id = '$id'";
 
 mysql_query($sql,$db) or die(mysql_error());
 
 echo "<script> window.alert('Convidado deletado com sucesso!'); </script>";
 echo "<script> window.location = 'javascript:history.go(-2)'; </script>";
   
 } else { // else do if ($_SESSION['7be4c2'] == 1122284) {
  echo 'Local Restrito! <br>';
     
 } // fim do else do if ($_SESSION['7be4c2'] == 1122284) {
?>
```

Estas próximas duas páginas não funcionam, sua unica diferença e estarem direcionadas para uma outra tabela de uma mesmo banco:

```html
<?php
session_start();
 if ($_SESSION['larj'] == '7be4c2') {

 include 'admin/conecta.php'; 

 include 'topo.php'; 
 
 $id = addslashes($_GET['id']);
 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM rsvp WHERE rsvp_id = '".$id."' ";
  $consulta = mysql_query($sql,$db) or die(mysql_error());
  $qtd = mysql_num_rows($consulta);
  while($item_temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
   $rsvp_array[] = $item_temp;
 } 
 
 
 $sql_eventos = "SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE eve_cli_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' ORDER BY eve_nome";
 $consulta_eventos = mysql_query($sql_eventos,$db) or die(mysql_error());
 $qtd_eventos = mysql_num_rows($consulta_eventos);
 while($item_temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta_eventos)){
  $eventos_array[] = $item_temp;
 } 
 /*
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($eventos_array);
 echo '</pre>';
 die();
 */  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> Organização de Eventos - Cerimonialismo - Consultoria</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
body,td,th {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
}
a:link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
}
a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
}
a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #FF6;
}
a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
}

.pics {  
    height:  232px;  
    width:   232px;  
    padding: 0;  
    margin:  0;  
} 
 
.pics img {  
    padding: 15px;  
    border:  1px solid #ccc;  
    background-color: #eee;  
    width:  200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    top:  0; 
    left: 0 
} 

</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 
 <script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="clearbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<table width="960" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10">
 <tr>
     <td width="908" colspan="4" align="center" valign="top"><br />                    
            <font color="#666666" size="3">
                <strong>Deseja Excluir os Dados do Convidado: <?php echo $rsvp_array[0]['rsvp_con_nome']; ?>?</strong></font>
            
            <form action="confirma_del_convidado_confirmado.php" method="post" name="confirma_del_convidado">
            <table width="750" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="40%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="60%"><font color="555555">*Todos os campos s&atilde;o obrigat&oacute;rios</font></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><font color="555555"><b>Evento:</b></font></td>
                <td>
                        <?php
       for($cont_ev = 0; $cont_ev < $qtd_eventos; $cont_ev++ ){
        if($eventos_array[$cont_ev]['eve_id'] == $rsvp_array[0]['rsvp_eve_id']){
         echo $eventos_array[$cont_ev][eve_nome];
        }
       }
      ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><font color="555555"><b>Nome:</b></font></td>
                <td><?php echo $rsvp_array[0]['rsvp_con_nome']; ?></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td align="right"><font color="555555"><b>Telefone:</b></font></td>
                <td>
                 <td><?php echo $rsvp_array[0]['rsvp_fones']; ?></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td align="right"><font color="555555"><b>E-mail:</b></font></td>
                <td><?php echo $rsvp_array[0]['rsvp_emails']; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right" valign="top"><font color="555555"><b>Mensagem:</b></font></td>
                <td>
                 <td><?php echo $rsvp_array[0]['rsvp_msg']; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><font color="555555"><b>Quantidade de Adultos:</b></font></td>
                <td><?php echo $rsvp_array[0]['rsvp_adultos_conf']; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><font color="555555"><b>Quantidade de Crianças:</b></font></td>
                <td><?php echo $rsvp_array[0]['rsvp_criancas_conf']; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                 <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="<?php echo $rsvp_array[0]['rsvp_con_id']; ?>" />
                 <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Excluir" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
            
  </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<table width="960" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="center">
         
        </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
 } else {
  echo 'Local Restrito! <br>';
     
 }
?>
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
 if ($_SESSION['larj'] == '7be4c2') {

  include 'admin/conecta.php'; 
   
   $id = addslashes($_POST['id']);
   //$atv    = addslashes($_POST['atv']);
   
   $sql = "DELETE FROM rsvp WHERE rsvp_id = '$id'";
 
 mysql_query($sql,$db) or die(mysql_error());
 
 echo "<script> window.alert('Convidado deletado com sucesso!'); </script>";
 echo "<script> window.location = 'javascript:history.go(-2)'; </script>";
   
 } else { // else do if ($_SESSION['7be4c2'] == 1122284) {
  echo 'Local Restrito! <br>';
     
 } // fim do else do if ($_SESSION['7be4c2'] == 1122284) {
?>
```

Já estou há algum tempo tentando resolver isto,mas as duas ultimas páginas não exercem alteração alguma na tabela, gostaria da colaboração de vocês para tentar identificar o erro.

Obrigado

Comment: Sua pergunta é muito grande para um problema relativamente simples, apesar de não ter nada de errado com isso do ponto de vista moderativo, é provável que desencoraje os participantes de ajudar. Talvez seria interessante você tentar restringir-se a mencionar trechos de códigos essenciais para reduzir a extensão da pergunta e facilitar para os leitores. Só uma recomendação.

Comment: Mysql é _deprecated_, nao tem a ver com o problema, mas de qq forma vc precisa revisar urgente isso, e trocar para funções mysqli_  - Outro problema é `addslashes`, Não sei de onde tirou isso, mas essa função não tem nada a ver com proteção de mysql, ao contrário do que uns desavisados ensinam errado pela internet. mysql se protege com funções próprias de escape. Quanto ao problema, pode ser simplesmente o fato do ID estar errado, o que não vai dar erro, mas também não vai deletar nada.